# Keras Model: Same array that is used for model.fit is not being processed in model.predict

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a model:

```
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim = X.shape[1], activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(8, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])
```

And during Model.evaluvate it works just fine with 'X' s input:

```
history = model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.2, epochs=10, callbacks=   [PrintDot()], batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

But during prediction as I use X[1] it throws an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_8_input to have shape (500,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

But X[1].Shape is (500,):

```
X[1].shape
--> (500,)
```

How can I mend this error, any help appreciated

Comment: Try giving it as (1,500), as predict expects (amount_of_items, features)

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Keras `model.predict` expects to receive input of `(amount_of_items, features)`.

So even when attempting to predict a single sample, you must reshape it to `(1, features)` , and in your case, `(1, 500)`.